# TFS - Daily Report on Checkins

Tags: tfs-2015

Is there a way to get a daily report on all checkins for a Project in TFS?

Additionally, can I get similar information about all hours entered in TFS for the previous day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **Daily Report on Checkins**, you can use the REST API to get the daily changsets information.

You can use below PowerShell script to query and export the changesets created on ***previous day***:

```
$project = "TFVC-Scrum"
$fromDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyy-M-d")
$baseUrl = "http://server:8080/tfs/CollectionLC/TFVC-Scrum/_apis/tfvc/changesets"           
$changeSetHistoryUrl = "{0}?api-version=1.0&searchCriteria.itemPath=$/{1}&searchCriteria.fromDate={2}" -f $baseUrl, $project, $fromDate #{1} is the first param $project, and {2} is the second param $fromDate
$changeSets = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $changeSetHistoryUrl -Method Get -UseDefaultCredential).value
$filename = $fromDate + "-" + "ChangesetReport"

$changeResults = @()

foreach($changeSet in $changeSets){
    $changeSetUrl = "{0}/{1}?api-version=1.0&includeworkitems=true&includeDetails=true" -f $baseUrl, $changeSet.changesetId

    $changeSetItem = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $changeSetUrl -Method Get -UseDefaultCredential

    $customObject = new-object PSObject -property @{
          "ChangeSetId" = $changeSetItem.ChangeSetId
          "CheckinNotesName" = $changeSetItem.checkinNotes.name
          "CheckinNotesValue" = $changeSetItem.checkinNotes.value
          "CheckedInBy" = $changeSetItem.checkedInBy.displayName
          "Comment" = $changeSetItem.Comment
          "CreatedDate" =  ([datetime]$changeSetItem.CreatedDate).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm")
          "WorkItem" = switch($changeSetItem.WorkItems.WorkItemType) 
                        {
                          "" {$null}
                         default {"[{0} - {1} - {2}] {3}" -f $changeSetItem.WorkItems.WorkItemType, $changeSetItem.WorkItems.Id, $changeSetItem.WorkItems.State, $changeSetItem.WorkItems.Title}
                    }
          "WorkItemAssignedTo" =  $changeSetItem.WorkItems.AssignedTo
        } 

    $changeResults += $customObject     
}

$changeResults | Select `
                ChangeSetId,
                CheckinNotesName, 
                CheckinNotesValue, 
                CreatedDate,
                CheckedInBy,
                WorkItem,
                WorkItemAssignedTo,
                Comment | export-csv -Path E:\$filename.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

For **Daily Hours** you can use third tools. Reference this thread: [TFS 2015 - Track Daily Hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38506365/tfs-2015-track-daily-hours)

- [Timetracker](http://www.tfs-timetracker.com/)
- [IMAGINET TIMESHEET](http://www.imaginet.com/imaginet-timesheet-for-tfs/)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the REST API for [TFVC](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/tfvc/changesets) or for [Git](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/git/commits) to retrieve information about changes made to those repositories. However, there are widgets that can be pinned to the team's dashboard to provide up-to-date information on recent commits.

For work items, you can retrieve all sorts of details about work items via the same REST APIs. However, the wording of your question ("hours entered") makes it sound like you're trying to use work items as a time tracker, which is not really how they're supposed to be used. There are plenty of third-party extensions that provide time tracking support, but providing tool recommendations is off topic for Stack Overflow and I honestly don't have much experience with any of them. Work items are typically used to keep tabs on how much work is **remaining** versus your initial estimates, not how much work **has been done**.

You'd be better served by stating exactly what you're trying to track and why you're trying to track it. There are probably good ways to surface the information you're after, but it really depends on the intended audience and the precise metrics you're looking to measure.